# How to silently refresh expired JWT token with OAuth2?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, jwt, microservices, refresh-token

We have decided to switch from Hazelcast shared session to Stateless JWT authentication/authorization with OAuth2 and found out a problem that doesnt fit our infrastructure described below.

[image: Current Hazelcast shared session]

So we have multiple Self-contained systems (scs) that may be accessed by direct link i.e. *mysite.com/scs1* and *mysite.com/scs2*.

[image: Stateless JWT so called Session]

Each scs has it's own UI and BackEnd, but "session" (implemented via Stateless JWT Authorization) has to be valid across multiple scs'es.

OAuth2 Authorizaion Server is a dedicated server (UAA).
In the OAuth2 terminology, each scs is a Resource Server.

Let's assume that user has logged into **scs1** (via UAA) and got JWT with TTL=10 minutes and RefreshToken with TTL=30 minutes. Then he leaves that tab in browser for 15 minutes. JWT expires, but the tab still contains the previous page from **scs1**. And user clicks a link on that page that follows to *mysite.com/scs3*.

**scs3** receives a request, checks JWT and finds out that it has expired. But we have a RefreshToken (still alive for 15 minutes) that may refresh JWT.

Is it possible to return a response from **scs3** that would ask browser to go to UAA and silently refresh JWT ?

[image: JWT has expired]

Maybe some kind of REDIRECT to /uaa/authorization with an ability to add RefreshToken Header?

Answer (score 4):

We have finally found out how to deal with token refresh in our case.

JWT has TTL=10min
RefreshToken has TTL=30min

Javascript, embedded in each page of our site refreshes JWT each 8-9 minutes. So when User has an opened tab in his browser, the refresh procedure will happen seamlessly.

A corner case is when User:

1. Opens tab mysite.com/scs1
2. Logs in
3. Closes tab
4. Waits 15 minutes. JWT expires, RefreshToken is still alive.
5. Opens new tab and enters mysite.com/scs1 or scs2 etc.

At this point the BackEnd receives only JWT which is expired.
So BackEnd redirects User to a dedicated web-page /try-refresh?**uri**=mysite.com/scs1

6. try-refresh page contains ONLY javascript which tries to refresh token and in successful case redirects User back to address from **uri** parameter